# list index out of range when converting from db file to csv and accessing the column wise data

Tags: python-3.x

I have converted a db file table to a csv file and trying to access the frst column using list comprehension but get list index out of range error but the same code works for other csv files. The code below is the code I used to access the csv file columns:

```
import csv
with open('vt_detection.csv','r') as vt:
  v_detect=csv.reader(vt,delimiter=',')
  vt_det=[v1 for v1 in v_detect]
with open('domain_info.csv','r') as domain:
  dom_cat=csv.reader(domain,delimiter=',')
  dom=[d1 for d1 in dom_cat]
with open('cat_info.csv','w') as domain:
  csvfile=csv.writer(domain,delimiter=',')
  csvfile.writerow(['domain','category','bitdef category','drweb 
  category','websense category','safety score','adult 
  content','verdict','parent domain','level','detection_timestamp','n 
  positives','n antivirus'])
  dat=[(l[0].strip(),l[1].strip()) for l in vt_det]
  print(dat)
```